# How to run web-inf js,css html file

Tags: javascript, java, css, tomcat

How to run and see the design without building application to war file, without starting tomcat server

This is the folder structure I have `  (his folder is from java ee application)
[image: This folder is from java ee application]

Comment: You can open the `.html` files in any browsers but probably won't see much. The resources (JavaScript/CSS/Images) wouldn't be able to be loaded and the html probably contains special thymeleaf markup that needs to be processed. So if you don't want to manually change all the html files you need a web server.